# GitHub Actions workflow for an iOS app build using Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, github-actions, workflow

I'm encountering an issue with a GitHub Actions workflow for an iOS app(Flutter) build using Xcode. The build process fails with the following error:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/Documents/fn7 files/GoogleService-Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
Encountered error while building for device.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Even though I have declared `GoogleService-Info.plist` in secrets, the workflow still shows it using a command output:

```
Run ls -la /Users/runner/work/fn7-mobile/fn7-mobile/ios/Runner
  
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   8 runner  staff   256 Jan 23 20:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 runner  staff   352 Jan 23 20:32 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 runner  staff   448 Jan 23 20:32 AppDelegate.swift
drwxr-xr-x   4 runner  staff   128 Jan 23 20:32 Assets.xcassets
drwxr-xr-x   4 runner  staff   128 Jan 23 20:32 Base.lproj
-rw-r--r--   1 runner  staff  1311 Jan 23 20:32 GoogleService-Info.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 runner  staff  2040 Jan 23 20:32 Info.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 runner  staff    38 Jan 23 20:32 Runner-Bridging-Header.h
```

Comment: The path in the error message and the path in your `ls` command are different.  I suspect that you have added your local copy of the plist file to the Xcode project without copying it to the project folder.  Either correct your Xcode project to refer to the correct path or ensure that your build workflow saves the secret at the correct location.